# PHP slashes in echo of a form

Tags: php

Im not really sure what to search for, but I was wondering if anyone would explain what the slashes in this code are used for.

```
echo
    "<form method=\"post\">
        <button name=\"test_button\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Send\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-custom\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"right\" > 
        <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-refresh\" style=\"font-size:.9em;\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>
        </button>
    </form>\n";
```

Comment: Just close your PHP tags, remove the `echo` (quotes and slashes) and print the HTML out normally.

Comment: their function is to escape the quotation marks (otherwise, the first instance of " would end the string & an error would be thrown). Learn about "string theory" here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use single quotes:

```
echo
    '<form method="post">
        <button name="test_button" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default btn-custom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" > 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="font-size:.9em;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </form>' . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your entire `echo` string is wrapped in double quotes (`""`), any instances of double quotes (`"`) inside the string need to be escaped by a back slash (`\`).